# The complexity of such function run in Matlab

Tags: matlab, python

The below function is representing an algorithm, so how can I get its complexity?  I don't mean the time of running by using the tic .. toc, I mean how many operation (Additions and multiplications) are performed in this loop.

```
for times=1:m;                                    
    for col=1:N;                                  
        product(col)=abs(T(:,col)'*r_n);          
    end
    [val,pos]=max(product);                      
    Aug_t=[Aug_t,T(:,pos)];                      
    T(:,pos)=zeros(M,1);                         
    aug_y=(Aug_t'*Aug_t)^(-1)*Aug_t'*Yy;          
    r_n=Yy-Aug_t*aug_y;                            
    pos_array(times)=pos;                        
end
```

Size of parameters, `m = 256` , `N = 256`, `T= [256,256]` and `M = [256,1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should know what each operator (i.e., `*`) and each called function (i.e. `product`) does.  Then add up those operations.  For instance, I'm pretty sure that in Matlab, the way you're building up `Aug_t` means that `Aug_t' * Aug_t` generates a vector dot-product, so for each element in `Aug_t` there's a multiply-accumulate.